# How to give a list to cond?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

We have a number of clauses (condition body) which we want to give to `cond`, like so:

```
(cond (condition1 body1)
      (condition2 body2)
      (condition3 body3))
```

But imagine that the clauses were first generated via `mapcar`, which gave the following list:

```
((condition1 body1)
 (condition2 body2)    
 (condition3 body3))
```

Let's say that the above list is the content of variable `clauses`.
Now, we would like to pass it to `cond`, but if we do the following:

```
`(cond ,clauses)
```

it results in:

```
(cond ((condition1 body1)
       (condition2 body2)
       (condition3 body3)))
```

which does not work, instead of:

```
(cond (condition1 body1)
      (condition2 body2)
      (condition3 body3))
```

Is there a way around this problem ?

Comment: How about just `mapcar`-ing down the list of `clauses` and test each condition during that process (you can use a `catch` and `throw` done once a condition tests positive to stop the `mapcar` dead in its tracks), instead of trying to force it into a particular format of `(cond (. . .`?

Comment: How about using apply?

Comment: Are you inside a macro? Can you give some example code here that shows what you're trying to do on a slightly higher level?

Comment: @Dan, you cannot apply special form, only functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to *splice* the list into the new form:

```el
`(cond ,@clauses)
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Backquote` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> You can also "splice" an evaluated value into the resulting list,
>   using the special marker `,@`.  The elements of the spliced list become
>   elements at the same level as the other elements of the resulting list.
>   The equivalent code without using `` ` `` is often unreadable.  Here are
>   some examples:

```el
     (setq some-list '(2 3))
          ⇒ (2 3)
     (cons 1 (append some-list '(4) some-list))
          ⇒ (1 2 3 4 2 3)
     `(1 ,@some-list 4 ,@some-list)
          ⇒ (1 2 3 4 2 3)

     (setq list '(hack foo bar))
          ⇒ (hack foo bar)
     (cons 'use
       (cons 'the
         (cons 'words (append (cdr list) '(as elements)))))
          ⇒ (use the words foo bar as elements)
     `(use the words ,@(cdr list) as elements)
          ⇒ (use the words foo bar as elements)
```

Comment: I'd also add the equivalent code without backquote, namely `(cons 'cond clauses)`